# Direct2D bitmap RAM usage optimization

Tags: c++, direct2d

Currently I wrote some code that loads original image with WIC, stores it in variable as `ID2D1Bitmap*` and then creates another resized one, via compatible render target and scale effect (I can provide example, if needed), so, for every basic image I have two bitmaps.

However, bitmaps use a lot of ram — loading just 10 2mb images costs more than 100mb of ram. I don’t understand why it uses ram at all, if it should be in GPU memory, as I understand.

So, I asking here the solution to reduce that ram usage.

I read about [atlas method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/improving-direct2d-performance#bitmaps), but it seems to be hard to develop. Maybe there are another tricks?

Example of code

```
#include <Windows.h>

HDC hdcDevice = GetDC(NULL);
int xw = GetDeviceCaps(hdcDevice, HORZRES);
int yw = GetDeviceCaps(hdcDevice, VERTRES);

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <wincodec.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwrite.lib")

using namespace std;

template<class Interface>
inline void SafeRelease(
    Interface** ppInterfaceToRelease)
{
    if (*ppInterfaceToRelease != NULL)
    {
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease) = NULL;
    }

}

ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap;

ID2D1Factory* factory;
IWICImagingFactory* d2dWICFactory;
IWICFormatConverter* d2dConverter;
IDWriteFactory* writeFactory;
IWICFormatConverter* d2dConverter2 = nullptr;
ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget* back = nullptr;
ID2D1DeviceContext* tar = nullptr;
ID2D1DeviceContext* target = nullptr;

ID2D1Effect* scale = nullptr;

class UIElement
{
public:
    ID2D1Bitmap* imgOrig;
    ID2D1Bitmap* img;
    D2D1_SIZE_F si;
    ID2D1DeviceContext* tar;

    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;

    UIElement(ID2D1DeviceContext *tar, float x, float y, float width, float height)
    {
        this->tar = tar;
        this->x = x; this->y = y; this->width = width; this->height = height;
        this->img = nullptr;

        scale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_INTERPOLATION_MODE, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY_CUBIC);
    }

    void setBackgroundImage(const wchar_t* path)
    {
        IWICBitmapDecoder* d2dDecoder;
        IWICBitmapFrameDecode* d2dBmpSrc;

        IWICFormatConverter* d2dConverter2 = nullptr;
        d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&d2dConverter2);

        d2dWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(path, NULL, GENERIC_READ,
            WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &d2dDecoder);
        if (d2dDecoder)
        {
            d2dDecoder->GetFrame(0, &d2dBmpSrc);
            if (d2dBmpSrc && d2dConverter2)
            {
                d2dConverter2->Initialize(d2dBmpSrc, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);

                tar->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(d2dConverter2, NULL, &imgOrig);

                if (imgOrig)
                {
                    si = imgOrig->GetSize();

                    RescaleImage();
                }
            }
        }

        SafeRelease(&d2dConverter2);
        SafeRelease(&d2dDecoder);
        SafeRelease(&d2dBmpSrc);
    }

    inline void RescaleImage(ID2D1Bitmap* cache = nullptr)
    {
        SafeRelease(&img);
        tar->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(width, height), 0, 0, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE::D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
        ), &img);

        if (cache != nullptr)
            scale->SetInput(0, cache);
        else if (this->imgOrig)
            scale->SetInput(0, this->imgOrig);

        scale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_SCALE, D2D1::Vector2F(this->width / si.width, this->height / si.height));

        ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget* rnd = nullptr;
        tar->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(D2D1::SizeF(width, height), &rnd);
        ID2D1DeviceContext* rndc = nullptr;
        rnd->QueryInterface(&rndc);

        rndc->BeginDraw();
        rndc->DrawImage(scale);
        rndc->EndDraw();

        img->CopyFromRenderTarget(0, rndc, 0);

        SafeRelease(&rndc);
        SafeRelease(&rnd);
    }

    inline void Render()
    {
        D2D1_RECT_F rect = D2D1::RectF(this->x, this->y, this->x + this->width, this->y + this->height);

        if(img)
        this->tar->DrawBitmap(img, rect);
    }
}*elements[100] = { NULL };


inline void Render()
{
    tar->BeginDraw();
    tar->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(1,1,1,1));

    target->BeginDraw();
    target->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(1,0,1,1));

    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && elements[i]; i++)
        elements[i]->Render();

    auto hr = target->EndDraw();

    tar->DrawImage(bitmap);

    hr = tar->EndDraw();


}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hin, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcDevice);

    WNDCLASS c = { NULL };
    c.lpszClassName = L"asd";
    c.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    c.hInstance = hin;
    c.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    c.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    c.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    RegisterClass(&c);

    int cx = 500, cy = 500;
    int x = xw / 2 - cx / 2, y = yw / 2 - cy / 2;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"asd", L"asd", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, x, y, cx, cy, NULL, NULL, hin, 0);

    HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);
    CoInitialize(NULL);


    D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE::D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_MULTI_THREADED, &factory);
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IWICImagingFactory), (void**)(&d2dWICFactory));
    d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&d2dConverter);
    DWriteCreateFactory(
        DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
        __uuidof(writeFactory),
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&writeFactory)
    );
    d2dWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&d2dConverter2);

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(cx, cy);
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* a = nullptr;
    factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size), &a);//);
    
    a->QueryInterface(&tar);
    
    tar->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&back);
    back->QueryInterface(&target);
    back->GetBitmap(&bitmap);

    target->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Scale, &scale);
    scale->SetValue(D2D1_SCALE_PROP_INTERPOLATION_MODE, D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_INTERPOLATION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY_CUBIC);

    MSG msg;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        elements[i] = new UIElement(target, 50*i, 10, 50, 50);
        elements[i]->setBackgroundImage(L"bitmap.bmp");
    }


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        Render();
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wp, lp);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

*I want Windows 7 support.

Comment: Uncompressed bitmaps in memory use memory, there's not much to add to that. However, why it seems to reside in CPU vs GPU is another question. Can you post a small reproducible sample: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier, I added example. So, You wrote about uncompressed bitmaps, I probably should search how to compress them

Comment: @SimonMourier, as You can see in my case, if to use atlas (and if it will solve the problem at all, of course), I need to write solution to dynamically handle it - calculate empty area, free area when the ui element is deleted, and reorganize the atlas again. Seems to be hard to write, but of course I will, if it is the solution

Comment: WIC is a CPU-only technology, if you store WIC bitmaps, you consume normal RAM.

Comment: @SimonMourier, well, as I remember I saw only WIC-based solutions on loading bitmaps. Oh, no, also saw from `HBITMAP` conversion here. So how should I load bitmap then?

Comment: @SimonMourier and what do You mean by *store WIC bitmaps*? I do not store WIC bitmap, I create `ID2D1Bitmap*` from `IWICFormatConverter*` and then release the converter, as You can see in the code.

Comment: Your code is largely incomplete. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier updated, though I think it was not necessary

Comment: @SimonMourier I also found (but already lost) Your another comment where You wrote about bitmap formats, like that you should multiply width on height on bytes per pixel of format, e.g. 256*256*32, so tried to choose another format in `IWICFormatConverter::Initilize`, but it either crashes or does not draw image

Comment: Your code is very convoluted, you pass bitmaps from CPU & GPU just to scale them, I do see committed CPU memory corresponding to WIC bitmaps, it seems there's still a link with the WIC Bitmap and the D2D1 Bitmap, not sure why, I can't reproduce with "normal" code. Why do you use D2D1 effect to scale while you can stay on CPU, use the IWicBitmapScaler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmapscaler and then pass that to GPU.

Comment: @SimonMourier what do You exactly mean by “pass to GPU”? Also I need ability to resize bitmap fast on the go

Comment: @SimonMourier, it seems that I found the solution based on Your thought about that wic bitmap somehow is not free: now I call `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` to intermediate bitmap, then create destination bitmap based on intermediate size, then copy from intermediate to destination and release intermediate. Now, storing 10 unique 2mb png images (and their scaled duplicates) costs… Actually it has weird behavior: for about half minute it costs ~25mb, but after ~5mb RAM. Earlier it ate ~120mb.

Comment: If you're happy you should answer yourself and post the corrected code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Mourier pointed in comments, it seems that in my code WIC bitmap's memory, allocated at RAM is not being free, even despite on realizing all wic's com objects.

So, I tried to get bitmap from wic not to final direct2d bitmap I need but for temporary direct2d bitmap, then create empty final direct2d bitmap, copy there temp bitmap and release temp bitmap.

This worked, now with 10 2mb png images (with their resized duplicates) my program uses few megabytes of RAM, and earlier about 120mb.

```
// WIC loading stuff

ID2D1Bitmap *temp = nullptr;
ID2D1Bitmap *imgOrig = nullptr;

target->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(d2dConverter, NULL, &temp);

if (temp)
{
    D2D1_SIZE_F size = temp->GetSize();

    target->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(size.width, size.height), 0, 0, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
                        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT::DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE::D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
                    ), &imgOrig);

    imgOrig->CopyFromBitmap(0, temp, 0);
    SafeRelease(&temp);
}

// Release WIC
```